# Angularjs missing scope values for ng-init using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I have following html in my page

```
<div ng-repeat="a in loc" ng-init="getValues(a)">
          <div>
           <select  ng-options="c.id as c.site for c in names" ng-model=a.id></select>
         </div>
           <div>
           <select  ng-options="a.id as a.name for a in val"></select>
         </div>
   </div>
```

In my controller I have

```
   $scope.getValues = function(a) {
        $scope.val = pRepository.getVals.query({ id: a.ie }, function (data) {
            $scope.val = data;
       });
```

Problem I have is when "loc" list in ng-repeat is small with one or two records it works fine. When it is long with 20 records or so it misses bunch of $scope.val values and lists some of them.
I tried using $promise but no luck.
Please let me know how can i slow down ng-repeat or something so it loads all the vals. 
Thanks

Comment: The problem won't be with ng-repeat it will most probably be an issue with asynchronous behaviour when populating loc.

Comment: @J.Davidson: Did you try my solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Every time `getValues(...)` is called the **same** `$scope.val` property is updated (it is the `val` property of the parent of the scope created by `ngRepeat`. Since you need to have a "local" `val` property, you should modify the code accordingly:

```
<div ng-repeat="a in loc" ng-init="values = getValues(a)">
    ...
    <div>
        <select ng-model="someModel" ng-options="a.id as a.name for a in values">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

$scope.getValues = function(a) {
    var data = [];
    pRepository.getVals.query({id: a.ie}, function (data) {
        data = data;
    });
    return data;
}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/ch6C8/)**.